# UISearch rearrange the indexpath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchbar

I have a `UiSearchBar` implemented in my `TableView`, and I also have two `NSArray`s, one for title and one for description. When I search through the array of the titles, it returns the right search, but when I click on a row that the search came with, I get "row 0" if I click on the first row. My question is how to make a connection between the two arrays so that when the search rearranges the titles based on the user search, the description array corresponds to the same row the title is at.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use two `NSArray`s, but just one with custom `NSObject` objects:

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject {
    NSString *_title;
    NSString *_description;
}

- (BOOL)matchesKeywords:(NSString *)keywords;

@end
```

Then you have all your information stored in one class, the way Obj-C is meant to be. You can easily perform the search because the objects itself *sort of knows* whether it matches a given keyword, so when you'd like to change `SomeObject` you can easily manage those changes in the class itself.

Comment: can you please show me how to use this method that you provided in the implementation class [  - (BOOL)matchesKeywords:(NSString *)keywords;
 ]
my arrays are stored in a property list.

i have tried so many ways and search all over the net, but can't figure it out.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I did merge the two arrays into one, but that made the tableviewcell load alot slower because the cell is holding both, the title and description

Comment: That really can't be true. You're only assigning a *pointer* to an object to the cell, not the object itself. And please use StackOverflow how it's meant, using the question/answer/comments mechanism, then I'd be able to see when there is some activity here. Now, I won't get notified about new answers.

Comment: i have managed to merge the two arrays into one in plist like this

key   type   value

_________________________________________________________

root   Array   (2 items)

item 0   dictionary  (2 items)

 title  String   book1

 description String   this is a red book


item 2   dictionary  (2 items)

 title  String   book2

 description String   this is a white book


but in the textDidChange: method, i could't  make it work

 for(NSString *name in [sourceData valueForKey:@"title"])
 {
......
......
 [[tableData valueForKey:@"title"] addObject:name]; 

please!!! help 
i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once So for the quick fix I did this:
In the header:
BOOL usingFilterArray;

Where you switch between the complete dictionary and the filtered one simply set the above BOOL to NO and YES respectively.

then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath use "if" statement to check the sate of the usingFilterArray.
Rest should be pretty easy. (Let me know if you still need help)
Just one thing when you perform the search after the filter Dictionary is hydrated if you cancel the search you need to make sure to run this or your app is going to crash as the hydrated dictionary will not have any object in it. (I assumed you cleaned the filtered Dictionary)

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Mate this is just a quick fix.